# Why are folders not deleted when I come back to a previous branch in GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio to manage two branches in git (Branch A and Branch B).
Today I merged branch A into B.

I made sure everything was ok by doing a `git checkout B`. Once I saw that everything was ok, I did a `git checkout A`, in order to continue working in branch A.

After I did a `git checkout A`, I found new folders in my working directory, these are folders that belong to branch B. Why did git not remove these folders when I did a `git checkout A`?

Actually, after I checked out branch A, one folder contained a new .csproj file (which exists only in branch B) and another folder contained a modified .sln file (contents of this file were from branch B, which I had to Undo Changes.

Comment: Do these folders contain files?

Comment: Perhaps because there were temporary ignored files (like `*.obj`). On checkout `git` doesn't remove them so it doesn't remove these directories.

Answer (score 2):

Git works with files, not folders. It sounds like you are in the following situation:

```
Branch A:

root
└── dir1
    ├── file1

Branch B:

root
├── dir1
│     ├── file1
├── dir2
      ├── file2
```

When you switch from branch `B` to branch `A` `dir2/file2` is removed, because it does not exist on branch `A`, but `dir2` will still exist as an empty directory. This is not a problem, you can ignore those empty folders or delete them if you wish.

EDIT: There are two cases in which files will be seen after switching branches, and based on your description I believe this is what you're experiencing:

1. You create new files while on `branch B`, you don't commit them, but you add them to `.gitignore`. While on `branch B` you don't see those files as being changed because git ignores them. When you switch back to `branch A` git will not remove them because they are untracked, but since they are no longer ignored on `branch A` you will see those files as being modified. You can remove all these files with [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) by running `git clean -X` while you are still on `branch B`.
2. You create new files while on `branch B`, but you don't commit them. While on `branch B` you will see those files as being modified (as you'd expect). When you switch back to `branch A` git will not delete those files because they are not tracked so you will still see them as modified.

Comment: Git *will* **sometimes** delete an empty folder. It is supposed to, if it created the folder earlier to put a file in it. I have seen it "forget" now and then and have never been able to properly characterize the situation. As you note, though, it's not really a problem.

Comment: @icebp After I checked out branch A, the folders contained a new .csproj file (which exists only in branch B) and another folder contained a modified .sln file (contents of this file were from branch B. I will update my question to include this information.

Comment: Where those files ignored on branch B? Or where they tracked by branch B?

Comment: @icebp No, these files are not ignored on branch B. But your second question has me thinking. How can I check if they are tracked in branch B?

Comment: `git ls-files` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) can be used to check the files that are tracked. Alternatively you can switch to branch B and see what `git status` tells you.

Comment: According to 'git ls-files', yes, they are being tracked. Both the .sln file and the .csproj file. On branch B.